# Change image when a link is clicked

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, hyperlink, src

Have a page that shows "logo.jpg" on page load. Would like to replace image with "issue8.jpg" when clicking "current issue" link. Believe this needs AJAX but wondering what the simplest method would be since it's only replacing one image with another.

The overall goal is to have a simple page load with a logo. When the user clicks the link "current issue" it loads an image of the current issue into the same div. Both images would have the same formatting, all I'd like to change is the image source from logo.jpg to issue8.jpg

Thanks for any pointers, I really appreciate it. Pretty stuck!

Comment: Not sure exactly how to implement that script in the html, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#currentIssue").click(function(){
    $("#myimg").attr("src","issue8.jpg");//.on("load",function(){});
});
```

or more generic

```
$(".issues").click(function(){
    $("#myimg").attr("src", $(this).data("img") );
});
```

Comment: So will I be using the id #myimg on the img tag that I want to change the source of? And do I use the .issues class on the link that when pressed changes the image?

Comment: it's a possibilitie, just adapt to your needs, the real answer for switch img source is the .attr("src","hey.jpg");

Answer (score 1):

In within scipt tag

function changeImage()

{

```
    element=document.getElementById('myimage')

            if (element.src.match("1"))

            {

                    element.src="2.jpeg";

            }

            else

            {

                    element.src="1.jpeg";

            }
```

}

set image id as myimage.